# maxdelta equivalent for Fruchterman-Reingold layouts in igraph 1.0?

Tags: r, igraph

Given a temporal graph (with a time attribute in every edge) I had a script to plot the evolution of the graph using a Fruchterman-Reingold layout. My script was based on this example: [Temporal Networks with igraph and R with 20 lines of code](http://estebanmoro.org/2012/11/temporal-networks-with-igraph-and-r-with-20-lines-of-code/).

One of the tricks was to start computing the layout for the current snapshopt `t` from the layout of the last snapshot `t-1`, and then limiting the nodes displacement with `maxdelta` so that there is a sense of smooth transitions between snapshots. Here is an animated example: https://vimeo.com/53071346

In igraph 1.0, the layout function `layout.fruchterman.reingold` becomes `layout_with_fr` and the `maxdelta` parameter disappeared and transitions between snapshots are too jumpy.

How can we achieve the same effect in igraph 1.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noticed, the Fruchterman-Reingold layout has been rewritten from scratch in igraph 1.0, and the `maxdelta` argument disappeared as a "side effect" (the new implementation does not support it). I don't know whether the new implemenetation misses the argument only because there was no time to implement or because there's an inherent limitation that prevents the implementation, but either way, please file an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/igraph/igraph/issues). I cannot make any promises as I did not write that part of the code, but maybe it will get re-added soon.

In the meanwhile, by looking at the [source code of the algorithm](https://github.com/igraph/igraph/blob/master/src/layout_fr.c#L31), it seems like the temperature parameter is acting as a limiting factor on the maximum displacement. You could try sending the maximum displacement as `start.temp` and set the number of iterations to 1 - this will limit the displacement to `start.temp` along both the X and the Y axis.

Another alternative is the `layout.graphopt()` function, which seems to support limiting the maximum displacement directly with the `max.sa.movement` parameter.

Comment: Thanks Tamás, another solution I found in the meanwhile is to use just one layout (the final layout) for all the animation. Is not that spectacular but it gets the job done :)